# How to add views to scrollview dynamically?

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I'm tring to add layout views in a scrollView dynamically. i know how to use ListView but in this case i dont want to use ListView. 
So, first i inflate the layout to view, and than add it to linearLayout inside the ScrollView. the problem is that i can't adding the layout multiply time.

```
View layoutInflated;
ScrollView scrollView;
LinearLayout childView;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_matan);


    scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_view_container);
    childView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_row_container);
    layoutInflated = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_message, scrollView, false);

    childView.addView(layoutInflated);

}
```

main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:onegravity="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view_container"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:fillViewport="false" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_row_container"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

layout "row":

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:onegravity="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolBar"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="15dp">
        <include android:id="@+id/rte_toolbar_container" layout="@layout/rte_toolbar"



            />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="14.23"
     >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/box"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/row_imgMail"
                            android:layout_width="25dp"
                            android:layout_height="25dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                            android:src="@drawable/icon_google" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/row_txMailAddres"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="left|center"
                            android:text="mail@gmail.com"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="15sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <CheckBox
                            android:id="@+id/row_cbMail"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:button="@drawable/checkbox_custom" />

                        <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/row_btnMagic"
                            android:layout_width="23dp"
                            android:layout_height="23dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_apply_all_accounts" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/shadow_bottom" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:button="@drawable/checkbox_custom" />
    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any idea how to do it ?

Comment: why don't you use **loops**? :)

Comment: I'm used but the app crashes

Comment: Why are you using multiple LinearLayouts?

Answer (score 0):

**Just use ListView or RecyclerView. Really!**

And trust me, this is best thing you can do here.